# Java JFrame/Swing alignment

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I'm new and learning JFrame currently and I'm running into a problem with the alignment of my ComboBox, checkboxes and buttons. The listeners are not hooked up yet and this is just a test to see if it's aligned properly. My question is why doesn't the alignment function seem to be working? I want the combo box to be at the top the checkboxes in the middle and the buttons on the bottom. [image]

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class CheckBoxFrame extends JFrame 
{

private final JComboBox<String> colorComboBox; 
private final JCheckBox backgroundColorCheckBox; 
private final JCheckBox foregroundColorCheckBox; 
private final JButton okButton;
private final JButton cancelButton;

private static final String[] color =
{"Red", "Blue", "Green", "Purple"};

public CheckBoxFrame()
{
  super("ColorSelect");
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());


  colorComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(color);
  colorComboBox.setAlignmentX(SwingConstants.TOP);
  add(colorComboBox);


  backgroundColorCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Background"); 
  foregroundColorCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Foreground"); 
  foregroundColorCheckBox.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
  backgroundColorCheckBox.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
  add(backgroundColorCheckBox); // add bold checkbox to JFrame
  add(foregroundColorCheckBox); // add italic checkbox to JFrame

  okButton = new JButton("Ok");
  cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
  okButton.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
  cancelButton.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
  add(okButton);
  add(cancelButton);


  // register listeners for JCheckBoxes
  CheckBoxHandler handler = new CheckBoxHandler();
  backgroundColorCheckBox.addItemListener(handler);
  foregroundColorCheckBox.addItemListener(handler);
  } 


private class CheckBoxHandler implements ItemListener 
{
  // respond to checkbox events
  @Override
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
  {

  } 
 }
} // end class CheckBoxFrame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Refer to the official docs on Layout Managers for Java Swing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html.
- `FlowLayout` is one of the more basic Layout Managers so I would suggest looking into the `GridBagLayout`.
- Try this:

```java
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class CheckBoxFrame extends JFrame 
{

private final JComboBox<String> colorComboBox; 
private final JCheckBox backgroundColorCheckBox; 
private final JCheckBox foregroundColorCheckBox; 
private final JButton okButton;
private final JButton cancelButton;

private static final String[] color = {"Red", "Blue", "Green", "Purple"};

public CheckBoxFrame()
{
  super("ColorSelect");
  setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

  GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  colorComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(color);
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.gridy = 0;
  c.gridwidth = 2;
  add(colorComboBox, c);


  backgroundColorCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Background"); 
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.gridy = 1;
  c.gridwidth = 1;
  add(backgroundColorCheckBox, c); // add bold checkbox to JFrame

  foregroundColorCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Foreground");
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  c.gridx = 1;
  c.gridy = 1;
  c.gridwidth = 1;
  add(foregroundColorCheckBox, c); // add italic checkbox to JFrame

  okButton = new JButton("Ok");
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.gridy = 2;
  c.gridwidth = 1;
  add(okButton, c);

  cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  c.gridx = 1;
  c.gridy = 2;
  c.gridwidth = 1;
  add(cancelButton, c);


  // register listeners for JCheckBoxes
  CheckBoxHandler handler = new CheckBoxHandler();
  backgroundColorCheckBox.addItemListener(handler);
  foregroundColorCheckBox.addItemListener(handler);
  } 


private class CheckBoxHandler implements ItemListener 
{
  // respond to checkbox events
  @Override
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
  {

  } 
 }
} // end class CheckBoxFrame
```

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly what I wanted it to do.

Comment: @MichaelFogarty Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [JavaDocs for `setVerticalAlignment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setVerticalAlignment-int-)

> Sets the vertical alignment of the icon and text.

This changes the way in which the `icon` and `text` properties are laid out WITHIN the context of the component.

`setVerticalAlignment` won't affect how the component is laid out in the container.

To change the way components are laid out in the container, you will need to change the layout manager, see [Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/)

Based on your requirements, there are number of ways you might achieve it.

You could use a `GridLayout`, which all the components for an individual row wrapped in their own `JPanel` and this panel added to the primary container.

You could also use a `GridBagLayout`, which, while more complex, is also more flexible

Comment: Thanks, I will look into GridBagLayout!